# Can a NAS serve as the single, local GitHub repo for several hosts?

Tags: git, nas

I have a few repos on GitHub. Up until now, I've used a single machine (a Mac) to host the local version of of these repos; i.e. they are located in the folder `/Users/seamus/Documents/GitHub` on the `Macintosh HD` for this Mac. Eeach repo has a sub-folder. Straightforward and simple to maintain for one user and one machine.

But I'm "branching out" a bit... I now have 3 Macs, an Ubuntu desktop, a few Raspberry Pis and I work on projects that are tied closely to a particular machine. For example, I have set up the IDE for my RPi Pico ucontroller on the Ubuntu box, whereas my Mac-related projects are on one of my Macs - which one depends upon whether the project is "vintage" or "current". And this may be important: I am the only "local person" working on these repos - there is no "team".

In summary, it has become awkward to have the local repo located on the `Mac HD` of one of my Macs. A potential solution would be to move my local Mac HD-based repo to my NAS drive - a Synology unit. I can mount a share on the Synology from all of my machines, and (it seems to me) this would solve my immediate problem by allowing me to work on any of my repos from any of my machines.

AFAICT the NAS-hosted local repo should work fine for my current situation (1 user, several repos). But I'm not proficient with `git`, so I wanted to ask if there are any obvious problems with this setup - or if there's a better way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with GitHub, does it?

Comment: @mkrieger1: It certainly does for me.

Comment: I meant: If you hosted your repositories somewhere else than on GitHub (say, GitLab or Bitbucket), your question would be the same.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused now. Are you using GitHub as the host for your repos (i.e. do you have a GitHub account and can you see your repos on https://github.com/your_username), or are you only using the GitHub client software to manage local repos on your hard drive? If you are actually using GitHub as a host, why do you want to host everything on a local NAS in addition to GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually unwise to mount a foreign (network-attached) drive as a *file system* and use it that way, i.e., as a shared drive, to host a Git repository.  The reason for this is that Git depends very heavily on POSIX semantics:

- that creating a file with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` works for creating lock files;
- that renaming a file with a single `rename` system call is atomic;

and various other things that often *don't* hold true for NFS, Samba, and other network-based file systems.  (But if you're careful to only use *one client at a time* and wait for all traffic to finish before moving to another client, you could consider risking that.  Almost all the POSIX-semantics-failure cases have to do with parallel use.)

Using a network device as a (pseudo) *disk drive*, for instance with iSCSI, usually *does* work.  But in this case you lose any advantages you were hoping to gain by using the NAS box.

If the NAS box supports Git, ssh, or HTTPS protocols, however, [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74488934/1256452) works fine: you have the NAS box provide a local bare clone, and you clone that local clone to each of the local machines on which you'll work.  You can push back to that bare clone, and—assuming the NAS box is sufficiently flexible—push from the bare NAS clone to the hosting (GitHub / GitLab / Bitbucket / whatever) server.

(FreeNAS and TrueNAS can do what you need since they're full blown Unix-y systems, running either FreeBSD or Linux depending on which configuration you use.  I'm not sure if Synology can, their boxes are a bit more opaque.)

Comment: The NAS box supports all of those protocols IIRC. I'm having difficulty translating the paragraph beginning w `If the NAS box...` into a *workflow*. It might make more sense to me if we got specific; i.e. if I called my currently-configured repo on host MyMac01 `RepoX@MyMac01`, and the "bare clone" on the NAS `RepoX@NAS`. If I am following, I need to: 1. set up a bare repo on the NAS called `RepoX`, 2) copy (as in `cp`?) all the files from `RepoX@MyMac01` to `RepoX@NAS`, 3) remove (?) `RepoX@MyMac01` from MyMac01, 4) clone `RepoX@NAS` to Mac01. Is that even close?

Comment: What I mean is: you use the NAS box to run Git. Log in, `cd /home/git; git clone --bare <github-url>` (assuming `/home/git` is appropriate here). You now have a bare clone in that location. You can now `git clone ssh://git@nasbox/repo.git` from the mac or the rpi or whatever. This example uses ssh (which is my preferred setup, it's far simpler than https and more secure than `git://`), but other protocols will be pretty much the same, except that the location of the repositories on the NAS box probably moves.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I feel this is most likely the correct answer, but I've not yet been able to confirm that on my Synology box. Synology tech support is a bloody disaster! I chose Synology because I felt that if I bought their product I'd get solid support. That's what I get for thinking!! Anyway, I'd still like to confirm your answer before accepting it, and my apologies for the delay.

Comment: Not having actually used the Synology box (I based my "more opaque" comment on some stuff I learned from someone else who had) I can't really say for sure. If I were setting up a NAS today I'd use FreeNAS or TrueNAS myself, but I did actually work for iX briefly (on a project that got canceled, alas).

Comment: Oh, sorry - I wasn't soliciting an opinion on Synology... I've got that covered! :)  LOL <anecdote>I had a long phone conversation today with a Synology support engineer. He seemed to be a very decent fellow, and he acknowledged that Synology has some unresolved issues. I understand, but if you can't service what you sell, you shouldn't be selling - that's fraud.</anecdote> Anyway, I can't complete the Git server install on Synology now. If that persists beyond next week, I'll push Synology aside & try FreeNAS or TrueNAS on another box.

Comment: Confirmed correct answer, but NOTE: This will work on many (most, all??) NAS boxes, **but it will not work on Synology**. I won't go into the details, but if you're thinking of a Synology NAS, my advice is to think some more!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, intended usage of git, and even pretty straightforward.

You just need to make sure that the repositories on the NAS are initialized as *bare* repos. A bare repo is basically the contents of the `.git` directory, containing your entire project history, but without any currently checked-out working copy. This is what allows you to push to it.

For example:

```
# Assuming your NAS is mounted on /mnt/nas
$ cd /mnt/nas

# Initialize bare repository in /mnt/nas/some_project
$ git init --bare some_project

# Assuming your working copy lives in ~/some_project
$ cd ~/some_project

# Add the NAS repo as a remote, and push all branches to it
$ git remote add origin /mnt/nas/some_project
$ git push --all
```

If you have ssh access to your NAS, you can even skip the mounting step and use `username@hostname:/path/on/nas/some_project` as the remote. But you can't `git init` it in that way.

Comment: "Bare repo"... I was hoping to use the [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) from my Macs - will this be possible? In your last paragraph, you mention the NAS-hosted repos as "the remote" - is that term used to signify that the NAS is remote from any of the host machines I am (for example) making and commiting edits to the files in the repo?

Comment: I use neither a Mac nor GitHub Desktop, so I can't help you with that... but creating a bare repository is a one-off operation per repo, so it shouldn't affect your normal workflow. A "remote" is any clone of your repo that isn't the one you're currently talking about: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes